# How can I connect to a Netezza database from a Spark SQLContext

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, netezza

I have a Spark instance and I'm trying to connect to an existing Netezza datawarehouse applicance to retrieve some data.

Using SparkSQL's `SQLContext`, and according to [Spark SQL Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), this is achievable with the `read` method. I've determined that I need to provide the JDBC driver using `--jars` flag, rather than `SPARK_CLASSPATH` as in the documentation. The operation looks like

```
// pyspark
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options( ... ).load()

// spark-shell
val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options( ... ).load()
```

I can find some documentation about connecting to Netezza using JDBC, but not how to correctly pass the username and password. What are the 'options' I need to pass here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pyspark`

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:netezza://server1:5480/DATABASE', \
    user='KIRK', password='****', dbtable='SCHEMA.MYTABLE', \
    driver='org.netezza.Driver').load()
```

and in `spark-shell`

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
             "url" -> "jdbc:netezza://server1:5480/DATABASE", 
             "user" -> "KIRK", 
             "password" -> "****", 
             "dbtable" -> "SCHEMA.MYTABLE", 
             "driver" -> "org.netezza.Driver")).load()
```

Note that Netezza likes things in ALL CAPS. I don't know if this is necessary, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: A note on the ALL CAPS comment: this is true in practice in nearly all Netezza systems. However, there is a configuration setting that allows the system views to use all lowercase values. So, if uppercase doesn't work, try lowercase also.

Comment: Hi , instead of loading up whole table can I pass a query instead ?

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala Yes, you can. If you include a subquery and an alias (e.g. x) it will work for you - e.g. `"(SELECT * FROM table where id = 1) x"`

Comment: I'm having trouble writing to netezza from Spark, sometimes not even 50 rows : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590729/pyspark-to-netezza-write-issue